# Dual boot with two separate Ubuntu installation on two separate hard drives on the same physical machine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have one physical machine and two hard drives. In the beginning, I've installed an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on each of them (without having the other hard drive attached). Everything works fine as long as I'm attaching one hard drive at a time. But now, I want to setup a dual-boot grub so that I can choose between different hard drives/installations with both hard drives attached.

I've tried `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sdb` but it didn't work. It actually detects and adds the other Ubuntu drives installation on the grub menu, but when I choose it, a blank screen with a blinking cursor appears (it also ruins the other drive's grub).

Any guides would be appreciated.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS as best alternatives will vary. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  I have two installs on SSD and three on HDD. But only one grub is in control as all boot is from one ESP on sda for UEFI boot. I do have ESP on sdb, but default install only installs to sda.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend rEFInd:

https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Trying to use two different GUID's can be complicated, because you have to manually edit and configure grub.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.